# How to pass multiple dynamic request headers into curl in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl

I can't make `curl` to work with "`request_header`" array in `bash`.

When I pass an "`${request_header[@]}`" array into curl command line, it will not work as expected.

But if I hard code the "`-H`" one by one in the `curl` command line, it works!

**Here is the code for testing:**

```
#!/bin/bash

send_example_by_array() {
    local -a request_header=()
    
    request_header[0]="-H"
    request_header[1]="\"Accept: */*\""
    
    request_header[2]="-H"
    request_header[3]="\"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\""
    
    curl "${request_header[@]}" --verbose --silent --location "https://www.example.com"
}

send_example_by_array

send_example_by_hard_code_headers_in_command_line_one_by_one() {
    curl -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --verbose --silent --location "https://www.example.com"
}

send_example_by_hard_code_headers_in_command_line_one_by_one
```

Here is the output of `send_example_by_array`:

As you can see, the "--verbose" print the "double" accept: */* headers and output will not return the HTML page content at all.

```
> Host: www.example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: */*
> "accept: */*"
> "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5"
> 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
* stopped the pause stream!
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
```

Here is the output of `send_example_by_hard_code_headers_in_command_line_one_by_one`:

As you can see, the "--verbose" print the only one "accept: */*" header in this case, and it will return the correct HTML page.

```
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: www.example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: */*
> accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
> 
...
< content-length: 1256
< 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, the `request_header` is dynamic and it may grow dynamically and it can't be hard coded one by one.

What's problem when passing "`${request_header[@]}`" to `curl` command line? Why not working? and How to fix?

Comment: You're adding embedded double quotes in the array version: `\"`

Comment: Thank you, it works now by removing the double quotes in the array, it takes me hours to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Accept: ..."` is not a valid HTML header. Get rid of the double quotes surrounding it:

```bash
send_example_by_array() {
    local -a request_header=(
        -H 'Accept: */*'
        -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5'
    )
    curl "${request_header[@]}" --verbose --silent --location "https://www.example.com"
}
```